Bounding a Riemann sum by its integral limit?
Let $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ denote the space of complex $n \times n$ matrices and, for $a>0$, $a \in \mathbb{R}$ fixed, let $A: [0,a) \to M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ be a given function. I will write $A(t) = (A_{i,j}(t))$ the matrix. Suppose further that each entry $A_{ij}(t)$ is $L^{1}$ in $[0,a)$. Define:
$$\|A\|_{\infty} = \sup_{i}\int_{0}^{a}dt \sum_{j=1}^{n}|A_{ij}(t)|.$$
We can discretize the interval $[0,a)$ by fixing $N > 1$ a natural number and setting:
$$I_{N} = \{t_{m} = \frac{ma}{N}: m=1,...,N\}.$$
The spacing is $a/N$. In this case, I define:
$$\|A\|_{N} = \sup_{i}\frac{a}{N}\sum_{m=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{n}|A_{ij}(t_{m})|.$$
In other words, I replaced the integral over $t$ by its Riemann sum.
My question is: does it always hold that:
$$\|A\|_{N} \le \|A\|_{\infty}$$
for every $N$? And if not, what conditions should $A$ have for this inequality to be true?

Notation: Here $\{\cdot\}$ denotes the fractional part of a real number.
It is in general not true - take $n = 1$, and for convenience $a = 1$, and set $A(t) = f(\{N_0 x\})$ for some $N_0 > 1$, for any $f: [0, 1) \to \mathbb R$ with $\int f > 0$ and $f(0) = 0$.
Then for this $N_0$, we have that your Riemann sum is $0$ but your integral is $\int f > 0$.
Addendum:
Your inequality is true if $\sup_i |A_{ij}|$ is nonincreasing.
As an additional comment, it is possible for any (reasonable) choice of $A$ to find some sequence of partitions with mesh going to $0$ such that your inequality holds for all $N$. However it of course will depend on $A$, and you have to allow any point $t_m$ within the partition cell, not just the right endpoint.

Thanks very much! If I don't assume any additional property on $A$, does the inequality hold up to, say, a factor $N^{-p}$ for some $p>0$?

@InMathweTrust Hm, as my example shows, the Riemann sums can be zero, so I doubt it holds even up to a factor.
